# How to model a highscore with 1 million players in DynamoDB and prevent a hot key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to store game results in a DynamoDB table. Every user has one try and gets into the table with his score.

After the game I have to display a ranking. Therefore I need all user entries sorted by the score.

My first attempt looks like this:

```
Game | UserID | Score
0    | 101    | 222
0    | 202    | 44
0    | 303    | 345
```

Where **Game** is the *hash key* and **Score** the *Range key*.

To get a sorted leaderboard/highscore I just have to submit a query like that:

```
Hash key == 0
```

Nice! It also works for parts of the ranking; I just have to take the Range Key and a limit into the query.

As far as I've read, is my Game Hash Key considered as "Hot Key", which can lead to a bottleneck and throtteling.

I estimate 1 million entries with the same hash key.

Funnily amazon also provide some tutorials with the same approach (GameID as hash key).

Is this a valid approach or is there any other solution, to spread the hash keys and still have a sorted score?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon's example is assuming that there are many different games so writes are distributed across different hash keys.  It sounds like you are saying you have only one or a very few number of game ids so the table structure you describe could be a problem for you.  Also remember that "For a table with local secondary indexes, there is a limit on item collection sizes: For every distinct hash key value, the total sizes of all table and index items cannot exceed 10 GB. Depending on your item sizes, this may constrain the number of range keys per hash value" ([AWS Developer Guide: Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html)).

How could you improve this?  You could segment the scores into ranges and add the range to the hash key.  For example:

```
Game+ScoreBlock | Score | UserID
0+0             | 44    | 202
0+2             | 222   | 101
0+3             | 345   | 303
```

Where Game+ScoreBlock is your hash key and Score is your range key.  Here ScoreBlock = Floor(Score/100) but you could choose an appropriate divisor based on your score ranges.  To query this, you would separately keep track of the highest score block that currently exists.  Then to get scores from highest to lowest you would query for the highest score block and then for the next highest and so on.  Realistically, you are going to stop after you find the N highest scores so that isn't as bad as it sounds.

Comment: I guess, that would be a working solution! In order to prevent premature optimization I will wait until it becomes a real problem. (my items are very small, so I won't exceed the 10GB). 
If it becomes real, I will try your solution. Thank you!